# sqlite: "no query solution" for covering index when column != "something"

Tags: sqlite

The following query throws a "no query solution".
aaa1 is an index containing`en_meros, en_ref, en_se`

```
SELECT en_family
FROM entries INDEXED BY aaa1
WHERE (en_meros<>6) AND (en_ref=0) AND (en_se=1) AND (en_lect LIKE "% abcd%" OR en_lect LIKE "abcd%")
```

If I change `en_meros<>6` to `en_meros=6` then it works, but I'm searching for NOT equal.

If I don't use any indices the query is slow (~500 ms).

If I use the individual indices of columns en_ref or en_se, it still is ~400ms

What should I do ? How can I solve this ?

Thank you in advance.

edit: the table's schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE [entries] (
  [en_id] INT, 
  [en_lect] TEXT(4096), 
  [en_example] TEXT(4096), 
  [en_opref] INT, 
  [en_meros] INT, 
  [en_main] INT, 
  [en_header] INT, 
  [en_se] INT, 
  [en_atono] TEXT(4096), 
  [en_family] INT, 
  [en_ref] INT, 
  [en_lectlexi] TEXT(4096), 
  [en_thama] TEXT(4096), 
  [en_meros2] INT);
CREATE INDEX [aaa1] ON [entries] ([en_meros], [en_ref], [en_se], [en_lect]);
CREATE INDEX [en_atono1] ON [entries] ([en_atono]);
CREATE INDEX [en_family1] ON [entries] ([en_family]);
CREATE INDEX [en_header1] ON [entries] ([en_header]);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [en_id1] ON [entries] ([en_id]);
CREATE INDEX [en_lect_en_ref1] ON [entries] ([en_lect], [en_ref]);
CREATE INDEX [en_lect1] ON [entries] ([en_lect]);
CREATE INDEX [en_main1] ON [entries] ([en_main]);
CREATE INDEX [en_meros1] ON [entries] ([en_meros]);
CREATE INDEX [en_meros21] ON [entries] ([en_meros2]);
CREATE INDEX [en_opref1] ON [entries] ([en_opref]);
CREATE INDEX [en_ref1] ON [entries] ([en_ref]);
CREATE INDEX [en_se1] ON [entries] ([en_se]);
CREATE INDEX [en_thama1] ON [entries] ([en_thama]);
CREATE INDEX [en_meros2_en_lect] ON [entries] ([en_meros2], [en_lect]);
```

Comment: Maybe because there are more rows with `en_meros<>6` than there are with `en_meros=6` and hence, it's taking time to fetch those rows?

Comment: MySQL and SQLite are two different rdbms products. Pls only use the relevant product tags.

Comment: Blindly making random changes is not useful. Show the database schema.

Comment: @CL. Just added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the query planning documentation ([Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html) and [The SQLite Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html)), it is not possible to use an index for searching for columns values with an inequality comparison.

Writing `INDEXED BY aaa1` does not change that; "no query solution" means that it is not possible to use that index at all, not even in a slow way.

---

Only the two equality comparisons can be sped up with an index, so you get the largest improvement by creating an index on those colums:

```
CREATE INDEX aaa2 ON entries(en_ref, en_se);
```

After an index entry has been found, the corresponding table row must still be looked up. To avoid this extra step, you could instead create a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) that also contains, after the lookup columns, all other columns that must be read by the query:

```
CREATE INDEX aaa3 ON entries(en_ref, en_se, en_lect, en_meros, en_family);
```

---

In general, you should not use `INDEXED BY`; it is useful only if the query planner has a choice between two indexes, and happens to choose the wrong one.

Comment: Would putting `en_meros` (an int) ahead of `en_lect` (a string) in the index be likely to make a difference? General "good advice" here and on the SQLite mailing list is to put "small" columns first, but since it won't be used during the indexed search, and all fields will be read anyway, perhaps not.

Comment: That would make a difference only if the later columns are not actually read, and are so large that they overflow a page.

Answer (score 0):

One still slow (~200ms) but better than no indices solution is:

```
SELECT en_family
FROM entries INDEXED BY aaa1
WHERE (en_meros<6 OR en_meros>6) AND (en_ref=0) AND (en_se=1) AND (en_lect LIKE "% abcd%" OR en_lect LIKE "abcd%")
```